# Is $x_0$ local minimum/maximum or inflection point if $f'(x_0)=0$?

Tags: calculus

Is the following statement true or false? (I think it is true, and I tried proving it by contradiction and failed.)

Let $f:(a,b)\to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable, and let $x_0\in (a,b)$ such that $f'(x_0)=0$. Then $x_0$ is a local minimum/maximum or inflection point.

Comment: What precisely do you mean by "inflection point"?

Comment: @ChrisEagle: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection_point

Comment: If you don't assume that $f''$ exists, then I think what you mean by *inflection point* (or *saddle point*) is that for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exist $x_1$ and $x_2$ in $(x_0 - \epsilon, x_0 + \epsilon) \cap (a,b)$ such that $f(x_1) < f(x_0) < f(x_2)$. In this sense, your claim is correct.

Comment: @Dominique: Defining "inflection point" to mean "point which is not a local extremum" makes the question rather uninteresting.

Comment: @ChrisEagle When $f'(x)=0$, that's exactly what we mean in optimization by *saddle point*: a stationary point that isn't a min or a max.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is false. Let $$f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2 \sin (1/x) & x \neq 0 \\ 0 & x=0\end{cases}$$
Then $f$ is differentiable and $f'(0)=0$, but $0$ is neither a local extremum nor an inflection point.

Comment: So, $f''(x)$ isn't exists, hence we cannot talk about inflection point, right? 
But why $x_0=0$ isn't local minima?

Comment: Because if for example $x=1/((2n-1/2)\pi)$ then $f(x)<0$.

Answer (score -1):

If $f'(x_0) = 0$, then the tangent to the curve $y = f(x)$ at $x = x_0$ is horizontal. Thus it is as you say.

Comment: Why does having a horizontal tangent imply the claim?

Comment: If the function is differentiable, where it is decreasing $f'(x) < 0$, where it is increasing $f'(x) > 0$. If $f'(x_0) = 0$, it isn't increasing nor decreasing there. It either reached a highest point and will start going down, it reached a lowest point and will start growing, or it is a turn (inflection point). Just plot $y = x^2$ or $y = -x^2$, or $y = x^3$ around $x_0 = 0$.